# making difflib's SequenceMatcher ignore "junk" characters

Tags: python, difflib, sequencematcher

I have a lot of strings that i want to match for similarity(each string is 30 characters on average). I found `difflib's` `SequenceMatcher` great for this task as it was simple and found the results good. But if i compare `hellboy` and `hell-boy` like this

```
>>> sm=SequenceMatcher(lambda x:x=='-','hellboy','hell-boy')
>>> sm.ratio()
0: 0.93333333333333335
```

I want such words to give a 100 percent match i.e `ratio of 1.0`. I understand that the junk character specified in the function above are not used for comparison but finding longest contiguous matching subsequence. **Is there some way i can make `SequenceMatcher` to ignore some "junk" characters for comparison purpose**?

Comment: It's kind of hackish, but any reason you couldn't just remove the _junk_ characters before doing the comparison? It's essentially the same thing as ignoring them.

Comment: yes thats good but i wanted to figure out if i could just do some `difflib` magic and get away with it otherwise i would have to pass the string through another function to first remove all junk chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to do as I suggested in the comments, (removing the *junk* characters) the fastest method is to use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

E.g:

```
to_compare = to_compare.translate(None, {"-"})
```

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python), this is significantly (3x) faster (and I feel nicer to read) than a regex.

Note that under Python 3.x, or if you are using Unicode under Python 2.x, this will not work as the `delchars` parameter is not accepted. In this case, you simply need to make a mapping to None. E.g:

```
translation_map = str.maketrans({"-": None})
to_compare = to_compare.translate(translation_map)
```

You could also have a small function to save some typing if you have a lot of characters you want to remove, just make a set and pass through:

```
def to_translation_map(iterable):
    return {key: None for key in iterable}
    #return dict((key, None) for key in iterable) #For old versions of Python without dict comps.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to make a function to remove all the junk character before hand you could use re:

```
string=re.sub('-|_|\*','',string)
```

for the regular expression `'-|_|\*'` just put a | between all junk characters and if its a special re character put a `\` before it (like `*` and `+`)

Comment: Is `-|_|\*` better than using `[-_*]` or are they equal efficiency wise?